# How to call https endpoint when AWS Lambda throws error?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a node.js application where I am invoking a lambda function through AWS SDK and I'm trying to handle lambda's errors in such a way that when it fails it calls an https endpoint from my application.

My application flow is as follow:

- Invoke lambda with object with data
- Lambda receives the object in the "event" and run its processes.
- if lambda fails either by runtime error, timeout, etc I need it to call an endpoint on my application, including the same object that I sent when invoking the lambda function.

I have thought of using CloudWatch alarms along with SNS to call my application endpoint, but I am not aware if that's entirely possible, specially if CloudWatch alarm can receive the lambda 'event' object.

How could I achieve calling an endpoint after Lambda has failed?

Comment: [AWS Batch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/what-is-batch.html) can do what you want though it may be overkill.  [AWS Step functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/welcome.html) could also work.  I would likely start by changing your Lambda's to save the trigger object first, perhaps in DynamoDB.

Comment: I have the object saved on a database, but I need a way to identify it when calling the endpoint, since on every lambda execution this object changes id. Would handling the lambda error by the response from AWS.Lambda().invoke be recommended?